# Angular importing 3rd-party JS library without typings

Tags: angular, skype, skype-for-business, skypedeveloper

I am looking to utilise the [Skype web sdk](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/websdk/docs/skypewebsdk) in an Angular (7) app.

To test it out I have added a script tag to my index.html

```
<script src="https://swx.cdn.skype.com/shared/v/1.2.35/SkypeBootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

First problem (apart from the documentation generally not being very clear from Microsoft), is that I need a typings file for the SDK. Does one exist? I can't find one. Unless I can then my next question - how do I deal with that in my app?

e.g.
in my component I am trying to initialize Skype but get the Typescript error

ERROR in src/app/home/home.component.ts(23,5): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Skype'.

What do I need to do in the Typescript constructor / import in order for the component to recognise the variable?

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import './SkypeBootstrap.min.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  Skype: any;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {

    Skype.initialize({
      //omitted
    });
  }
```

Comment: See this: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-third-party-lib

Answer (score 0):

If there is not a d.ts file for this lib you have to make it yourself anyway and then use 
`declare var Skype: any;` 
before class declaration, and then declare class field as usual

```
SkypeField: Skype;
```